# alternatives to dealing with react query is loading

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I've been using React for about a year and React Query for a couple months. However every component I make I find myself doing the same isLoading is error routine. Here is a simple example

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { fetchAllUsers } from "./useFetchUsers";

const TestComponent = () => {
  const data = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["Users"],
    queryFn: fetchAllUsers,
  });

  if (data.isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (data.error) {
    return <div>Error</div>;
  }

  if(!data.data){
    return <div>empty data</div>
  }

  if (data.data) {
    return <div>{data.data}</div>;
  }
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Can someone show me an alternative way to deal with constantly having to include .isLoading and .error on every component I make? I want to find a way of dealing with all the use cases without having to make my components be covered with if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to higher-order component(HOC) could be to create a component specifically for these three cases (loading, error, and empty data).

```js
const DataStatus = ({ isLoading, error, data }) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Empty data</div>
  }

  return null // to make sure nothing gets rendered. 
}

export default DataStatus
```

Then use it wherever you need it,

```js
const TestComponent = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["Users"],
    queryFn: fetchAllUsers,
  })

  return (
    <>
      <DataStatus isLoading={isLoading} error={error} emptyData={!data} />
      {data && <div>{data}</div>}
    </>
  )
}

export default TestComponent
```

I believe this approach is more flexible, specially when you have multiple useQuery statements in your component.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve this is with a data wrapping component that either passes the data down to its children (like in the component below). Or the children would use the react query hooks to access the cached data

```js
import { React } from "react";

const DataWrapper = ({ queryKeys, queryFn, children }) => {
  const data = useQuery({
    queryKey: queryKeys,
    queryFn: queryFn,
  });

  if (data.isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (data.error) {
    return <div>Error</div>;
  }

  // data is ready
  // render children with data
  if(!data.data) {
    return <div>EmptyState</div>;
  }

  if (data.data) {
    const childrenPopulated = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { data: data.data });
    });

    return <>{
      childrenPopulated
    }</>;
  }
}
```

The component would then get used like

```js
const TestComponent = () => 
  <DataWrapper queryFn={fetchAllUsers} queryKey={["Users"]}>
    <UserList />
  </DataWrapper>;

const UserList = ({ data }) => <div>{data}</div>;
```

Hope this helps, good luck with your implementaion